# Effect of leaving space after '-' in Ruby expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, math

Today I was trying something out in my Rails console and this happened,

```
2.0.0p247 :009 > Date.today -29.days
 => Fri, 07 Feb 2014 
2.0.0p247 :010 > Date.today - 29.days
 => Thu, 09 Jan 2014
```

I am pretty baffled. I can see that I am missing something basic. But it just inst striking my mind! Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I can see how this would be parsed differently: the first would likely be `(-29).days`, while the latter would be `- (29.days)`. That doesn't really explain the different behavior, though, but I don't know enough ruby for more.

Comment: Yes, that is understandable but the result is bizarre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What actually happens is this:

```
Date.today(-29.days) # => Fri, 07 Feb 2014
```

[`today`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today) has an optional parameter called `start`, which defaults to `Date::ITALY`.

> An optional argument the day of calendar reform (start) as a Julian
>   day number, which should be 2298874 to 2426355 or -/+oo. The default
>   value is Date::ITALY (2299161=1582-10-15).

Passing `-29.days` to `today` apparently has no effect.

Whereas:

```
Date.today + -29.days # => Thu, 09 Jan 2014
```

Which is the same as:

```
Date.today - 29.days # => Thu, 09 Jan 2014
```

Comment: `Date.today d` <--- what is happening between `Date.today` and `d`?

Comment: It's actually [`Date.today(d)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today).

Comment: Superb! Thanks!! Didnt know that `today` takes an arg. Awesome explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The `Fixnum#days` method in Ruby is defined in the `ActiveSupport` library in `Rails`. More specifically, it's defined in the 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time` module

#### Just loading ActiveSupport inside a console

```
> require 'active_support'
true
> require 'active_support/core_ext'
true

> 29.days
=> 2505600

> -29.days
=> -2505600
```

The code for the method `days` looks like this:

```
def days
  ActiveSupport::Duration.new(self * 24.hours, [[:days, self]])
end
```

The `self` object in this case is `29 or -29`. That gets multiplied by 2505600 which is a legitimate calculation and will return the amount of seconds that the number 29 represents.

With that in mind, in the first calculation, you're just passing two objects to the console input, the first one being a Date object and the second one being a number. Similar to sending the following:

```
> puts "test"
```

That is, the `-29.days` is passed as an argument to the object returned by`Date.today`. And `Date.today` accepts a parameter which specifies the start day of the calendar. [Refer to this answer to know the accepted days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835889/465082). If any non-recognized parameter is passed, the default start date is used (which is Date::GREGORIAN)

```
> Date.today
=> Thu, 09 Feb 2014

> Date.today Date::JULIAN
=> Fri, 25 Jan 2014
```

So Ruby checks if you passed in a valid start date constant or not and the decide on the start date.   For this reason, you still get today's date as the answer when running the first command.

The second command is simply the subtraction of one Date object with another object that is understood by Ruby as the number of seconds you want to subtract from today's date. `29.days` is internally converted to the number of seconds in both cases.

Hope that helps.