# Is it possible to format/convert date for 13 month calendar (Georgian Calendar )

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, date, momentjs

Some calendar reformers seek to equalize the length of each month in the year. This is often accomplished by creating a calendar that has 13 months of 4 weeks (28 days) each, making 364 days. The earliest known proposal of this type was the Georgian Calendar - [more details on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_reform)

### Reform calendar(Georgian Calendar)

[image]

I want to change the date `12-31-2016` to Georgian Calendar format .

If my date is `12-30-2015`.Is It possible to format/any way to `12-28-2016 or 01-02-2017` as well as Georgian Calendar?

Comment: Divide the total seconds of the year and provide any property name for the given period.

Comment: If you add it on the answer. I should mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the total seconds of the year and provide any property name for the given period.

Comment: Actually Sorry. I want the answer means need to be a full function with the calculation? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Not every year is exactly the same in seconds.  You can provide any "name" that you select for a given period. Set a "start"  second and an  "end" second; which are most important parts of equation. Use whichever format you choose to divide the total seconds within that period.

Comment: See also [What is the significance of 1/1/1753 in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server), [How do I use ruby Date constants GREGORIAN, JULIAN, ENGLAND and even ITALY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835193/how-do-i-use-ruby-date-constants-gregorian-julian-england-and-even-italy), [Why Our Calendars Skipped 11 Days in 1752](http://mentalfloss.com/article/51370/why-our-calendars-skipped-11-days-1752), [George II and the Gregorian calendar](http://leancrew.com/all-this/2013/01/george-ii-and-the-gregorian-calendar/)